# How to decide between strafing, turning etc for lateral character movement?

Tags: game-design, movement, character

I have been studying the character movement of many 3rd person games. But just when I think I have come to understand the conventions or found a pattern, it seems I come across another game which does the complete opposite. I understand that there will always be games that defy conventions, but I am trying to work out at least some basic guidelines to follow.

For simplicity sake I have narrowed down lateral movement into 3 categories:

**1) Directional Movement**

This is movement where based on input of any of the four main directions (forward, back, left, right), the character will move in exactly that direction. In otherwords they will usually do a quick turn towards their direction and then walk straight in that direction. Therefore the character is always facing where they are going. The Assassin's Creed series is a good example of this.

**2) Strafing**

Most popular in FPS games, but also used in shooter heavy TPS games such as Gears of War and the Max Payne series. Here the character faces forward irrespective of which of the 4 main directions they are moving in, and therefore strafes when moving sideways.

**3) Turning**

This is similar to strafing except that when moving left or right the character will turn in that direction, moving in a circular way. Games that use this movement style include the GTA series and recently the Uncharted series.

So based on this I am trying to determine how to decide which movement type is best for which type of game. At the moment I am considering to use (2) for when aiming weapons (since this movement is used in FPS games), and (3) for all other ground based movement. But I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: This is completely up to you and what you 'feel' is right for the game you want to make; better yet, try each in turn out (with users if possible) and see how it plays. There are conventions as you noted, however there is not really a best approach, just what fits with your game and the experience it provides

Comment: Sure but getting a feel for what is right and is not comes through experience; drawing on what was/was not successful in past situations. Without this experience, it can be easy to fall into the trap of making flawed assumptions. Often it is easy to work out that something does not quite feel right, why it doesn't feel right and how it can be improved is the real challenge. In my case, once I know more about the conventions relevant to movement I can use them as guidelines, then once I am confident with these conventions I can go beyond them and perhaps do things more by feel alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends primarily on what the player is supposed to do.

In games where a gun is facing in the walking direction and the main thing the player is supposed to do is to shoot things by accurately aiming the gun, it makes sense to point the camera and the gun in the same direction, so the player sees what they're shooting at. Disadvantages are that you can't look around without turning, and the camera usually turns very quickly, which will feel uncomfortable for some players and can cause nausea.

In a game where getting a good look of the surroundings is a lot more important than shooting people with a forward facing gun, you can decouple the walk and the view direction. This is especially important if the player will want to look in a certain direction without moving there. Disadvantages are that players not used to this control (or to video games in general) may have  difficulties with controlling view and movement direction independently.

The two can be merged, by splitting camera and movement direction but instead of giving camera control to the player, the camera automatically follows the movement direction in a slow and smooth movement. This makes the control easier and reduces the risk of nausea, but also removes the ability to aim or to look somewhere without turning the character. This gives less control to the player, but allows the game to reach a wider audience.

You can even change the controls for different parts of the game, e.g. toggle to 1) whenever you enter/leave stealth mode, or toggle to 2) when you use a scoped aim mode.

The primary goal should be to reach a wide audience, which you do by choosing the least frustrating control scheme. By going for 3) you do that, but if the game is heavy on stealth or ranged combat, you will likely need to implement option 2) or option 1) as well, or the player might feel frustration due to the limited controls. And as soon as you're using 2 different control schemes, you need to consider if the game won't be simpler if you just use 1 control scheme instead.

Comment: What surprised me recently was Uncharted 4 using turning instead of strafing; I thought that strafing was going to be used like in the Last of Us. I suppose the additional climbing in Uncharted was the reason for this?

Comment: @FrontEnd Updated the answer to take games like Uncharted into account.